# How to control multiple legends and linetypes in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using the code below, I'm trying to make a figure with a top and bottom panel/facet, while grouped by both status and category.

I want to do 3 things that I'm struggling with because of this interaction grouping:

1. Put the legends on top of each other, instead of side by side
2. Add labels to the status legend to be "Not Included" (for 0) and "Included" (for 1)
3. Change the linetype to be dotted instead of dashed

Code:

```
d %>% 
  filter(outcome != "alcohol") %>% 
ggplot(., aes(x = wave, y = mean, group = interaction(as.factor(status), category),
              color = category, linetype = as.factor(status))) +
  geom_point(size = 2.5) +
  geom_line(linewidth = 1.5) +
  facet_wrap(~outcome,
             ncol = 1,
             scales = "free_y") +
  labs(x = "",
       y = "") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

Data:

```
d <- structure(list(wave = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 1, 1, 2, 
2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 1, 1, 2, 2, 
3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5), mean = c(2.068, 
2.221, 2.044, 2.225, 1.965, 2.122, 2.269, 2.52, 2.416, 2.666, 
2.042, 2.237, 2.006, 2.256, 1.94, 2.176, 2.187, 2.5, 2.348, 2.668, 
2.053, 2.132, 2.069, 2.11, 1.998, 2.006, 2.4, 2.482, 2.593, 2.639, 
2.038, 2.189, 2.012, 2.177, 1.945, 2.127, 2.228, 2.5, 2.639, 
2.609, 2.166, 2.31, 2.132, 2.362, 2.067, 2.121, 2.458, 2.57, 
2.624, 2.815), category = c("all", "all", "all", "all", "all", 
"all", "all", "all", "all", "all", "white", "white", "white", 
"white", "white", "white", "white", "white", "white", "white", 
"black", "black", "black", "black", "black", "black", "black", 
"black", "black", "black", "nopoverty", "nopoverty", "nopoverty", 
"nopoverty", "nopoverty", "nopoverty", "nopoverty", "nopoverty", 
"nopoverty", "nopoverty", "poverty", "poverty", "poverty", "poverty", 
"poverty", "poverty", "poverty", "poverty", "poverty", "poverty"
), status= c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 
-50L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite everything you are looking for but requests 2&3 fixed and stacking the title on top of the legend is a slightly better than the original.

```
d %>% 
   ggplot(., aes(x = wave, y = mean, group = interaction(as.factor(status), category),
                 color = category, linetype = as.factor(status))) +
   geom_point(size = 2.5) +
   geom_line(linewidth = 1.5) +
   facet_wrap(d$status, ncol = 1, scales = "free_y") +
   labs(x = "",  y = "") +
   theme_minimal() +
   theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
   guides(linetype = guide_legend(title.position = "top", keywidth = unit(1.5, "cm")), color=guide_legend(title.position = "top")) +
   scale_linetype_manual(values=c("solid", "dotted"), labels=c("Not Included", "Included"), name="scale")
```

[image]